# Compile .tex with knitr via ssh

Tags: r, emacs, ssh, knitr

I have a `.Rnw` file on a remote machine which I edit via ssh with Aquamacs/Emacs. I don't want to compile the `.Rnw` locally because it would require to move all the data from the remote to the local memory. 
When I start to compile the file Emacs correctly ask me to start a data directory in the remote location. Yet after that I get the error

```
Loading required package: knitr
Error in setwd(dirname(file)) : cannot change working directory
```

Is it possible to use knitr via ssh?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that `knitr` will correctly produce a .tex when called from within R with `knit(file)`

Comment: Is installing Emacs on the remote machine a possibility -- along with the required binaries (if any) that may be needed to use `knitr`?

Comment: @lawlist Yes. What are you thinking?

Comment: I know it might be nice to run the stuff from your own end, but as long as you have privileges to run stuff on the remote server, then you can do everything over there.  However, it's not going to be a fancy GUI I don't think -- you'd be using Emacs on the remote server from your terminal on the local host.